# How can I keep a MongoDB FindIterable in Tomcat memory for better query performance?

Tags: mongodb, caching

I wrote a program which hope to keep recent mongo query result in tomcat memory,
The purpose is mainly for saving mongo query traffic.
For example, query student's name and home address which are not frequently change.

Per my understanding, the return docs should always the same if I don't do memery refresh.

However, once I update the student's address, and call the api below,
the docs return the latest changed result and not from memery.

Does this correct? Appreciate for your kindly suggestions.

```
//M is a hashspace use to hold recent queried result
//key means a query key, like student id

HashMap M = new HashMap(); 
FindIterable<Document> docs = null;
        
if(M.containsKey(key)) { 
  docs = M.get(key);
}
else {
  mongo.setColl(com.gds.SysConfig._DB, "student_info");
  docs = mongo.select({"stu_id": key});
  if(docs != null) {
    M.put(key, docs);
  }
}           
            
return docs;
```

The result should be return from the hash instead of query again from mongodb.

Comment: Does this create a `new` `M`, and therefore destroys the _old_ `M` with each call?

Comment: No, the M was defined as a static variable in java.